# How to assign equation number when equation written in tabular form

Tags: winedt

Tried to write a LPP in the following way. Now I want to assign a single equation number for the whole set. How should I proceed?

```
 \begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
Optimize 
        & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$z=c_1x_1 + c_2x_2$} \\
s.t.    & $a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2$ & $<=> $ & $b_1$\\
        & $a_{21}x_1 +a_{22}x_2$  & $<=>$ & $b_2$ \\
        & $x_1, x_2$  $\geq$  $0$ \\
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Don't use a `tabular`, wrap in an `equation` and replace `tabular` by `array` and remove all the `$`'s

Comment: Or use `align` or a similar enrivonment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `optidef` package, which is precisely dedicated to the layout of optimisation problems.

Comment: Works fine @daleif